# Is this the correct way to write an Apache Beam PCollection to multiple sinks?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-beam

I'm building a pipeline that eventually writes to two sinks (MongoDB, BigQuery). I've included a snippet of the pipeline below that is giving me some issues. Here is what happening: File contents (json objects) read into PCollection `elements`, then a series of transforms are applied resulting in another PCollection called `transformed`. This PCollection `transformed` is written to MongoDB without any issues. Now I apply one additional transform to the `transformed` PCollection before writing it to BigQuery. Here is where the error occurs when i execute the pipeline:

**TypeError: Cannot convert ObjectId('5ee110559926384724ff5a83') to a JSON value. [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)']**

I found that when i'm writing to MongoDb, it automatically adds an attribute "_id" for each document inserted (no problem here). But somehow, later on when i try to write to BigQuery, the elements within PCollection `transformed` now has this additional "_id" attribute. How strange is this? PCollections are supposed to be immutable right?

What i've tried so far - commenting out the part where it writes to BigQuery to see what happens. When i do this, it successfully writes the PCollection `transformed` to MongoDB but this other strange error appears:

**Exception in thread Thread-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1177, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/sdf_direct_runner.py", line 467, in initiate_checkpoint
    checkpoint_state.residual_restriction = tracker.checkpoint()
AttributeError: '_SDFBoundedSourceRestrictionTracker' object has no attribute 'checkpoint'**

```
elements, files_read = (
                p
                | 'ReadFromGCS' >> beam.io.ReadFromTextWithFilename(file_pattern=file_pattern, coder=JsonCoder())
                | 'aTransformWithTaggedOutput' >> beam.ParDo(aTransform()).with_outputs('taggedOutputFilesRead',
                                                                        main='elements')
        )

deferred_side_input_1 = beam.pvalue.AsIter((
                p
                | 'QueryFromBigQueryTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='SELECT col1 from dataset.table'))
        ))

deferred_side_input_2 = beam.pvalue.AsIter((
                p
                | 'ReadFromBigQueryTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(dataset='bq_dataset', table='bq_table'))
        ))

transformed, tagged_output = (
                    elements
                    | 'Series' >> beam.ParDo(aTransform())
                    | 'of' >> beam.ParDo(anotherTransform())
                    | 'transforms' >> beam.ParDo(anotherTransform())
                    | '...' >> beam.ParDo(anotherTransform())
                    | '...' >> beam.ParDo(anotherTransform())
                    | '...' >> beam.ParDo(anotherTransform(), deferred_side_input1)
                    | 'transformWithTaggedOutput' >> beam.ParDo(transformWithTaggedOutput(), deferred_side_input_2).with_outputs('tagged_output',
                                                                                 main='transformed')
            )


"""Write `transformed` PCollection to MongoDB"""
transformed | 'WriteToMongo' >> beam.io.WriteToMongoDB(uri='mongoURI',
                                                       db='mongoDB',
                                                       coll='mongoCollection')

"""Perform an additional transform to `transformed` PCollection, Write to BigQuery"""
_ = (
transformed
| 'AdditionalTransform' >> beam.ParDo(additionalTransform())
| 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                      table='bigqueryTable',
                      dataset='bigqueryDataset',
                      schema=beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.parse_table_schema_from_json(bq_schema),
                      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                      validate=True)
            )

"""(No issues with this write to BQ) Write `tagged_output` PCollection to BigQuery"""
    tagged_output | 'WriteTaggedOutputToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        table='other_bq_table,
        dataset='bq_dataset,
        schema=beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.parse_table_schema_from_json(other_bq_schema),
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        validate=True)
```

Comment: @Pablo Can you lend your expertise?